# Updating Quantal 12.10 to Raring 13.04 broke seahorse-nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 13.04, encryption, gnupg, seahorse

After upgrading from Quantal to Raring the nautilus-seahorse plugin for GPG encryption cease to work. When right clicking in a file the GUI opens and ask to select a key for encryption but the encryption never occurs. It is also impossible to desencrypt a file. The CLI works fine, it is only the Nautilus ( or now "files") plugin which does not work. Re-installing the plugin and other seahorse files from Synaptic did not help. Any idea ?

Comment: There may be a workaround for this but I would strongly suggest [reporting this as a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

That would be [bug 697895 in the Gnome Bugtracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697895)

So far all you can do is confirming the bug over there and wait. /: